# Does PHP define the result of accessing an uninitialized location in a sequential array?

Tags: php, arrays

I was researching a different question (ie, not the one described in the title of this post) and found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150220) on Wordpress Development Stack Exchange that appears to have a coding error.

```
$thisindex = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
$previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
$nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];
```

In any other language this would definitely be an error, since adding or subtracting 1, is likely to access an uninitialized location.

So, is the result of accessing an uninitialized array location in PHP undefined?  And, if not, then what is the result supposed to be?

Comment: if `$thisindex` returns `false`(not found) and a `-1` index doesn't exist on `$ids` then its an undefined index error

Comment: It might be worth noting that you could create a class that implements the ArrayAccess interface and you could override the behaviour for accessing undefined indexes to do whatever you wanted. Otherwise, it is also just easy to check isset($array[$key]) ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't really have sequential arrays. It might use a sequential data structure internally but to the programmer this doesn't matter.

In PHP arrays are key-value maps where keys can be integers or strings.

If you try to access an undefined index PHP will throw an `E_NOTICE "Undefined index"`. The result is `null`.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = "foo";
$arr[2] = "bar";
var_dump($arr[1]); // null + notice
```

The code snippet you posted is not necessarily wrong. If the precondition is that `$post->ID` is in `$ids` then it's fair that the output of `array_search` is not checked.

Comment: @Halcyon, thanks for the clarification.  I suspected as much.  Is this behavior the same for accessing any uninitialized data?  And is it documented anywhere?

Comment: The same applies to accessing undefined variables `var_dump($foo);` and undefined properties on an object `$o = new stdClass(); var_dump($o->foo);`. I tried searching for a list of `E_NOTICE`s that PHP has but I can't find it. Notices like these are serious programming errors but PHP accepts them anyway - this has do with legacy, PHP used to be a much simpler language and it's grown a little awkwardly. The common solution is bump up `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and throw all `E_WARNING`s and `E_NOTICE`s as Exceptions. This makes them (if uncaught) `Fatal` and will stop your script.

Comment: I will set the green check mark on this answer, but, in the absence of documentation, it is hard to be confident.  It sounds right, and I verified that, in my specific test case, I get consistent results.  But in the absence of an authoritative reference, it is hard to know if it is true in all cases.

Comment: If you want, you can open a bounty specifically to get more authoritative answers.